# Contextual meaning of the text

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

> "I'm very glad... That was a grand day we all had—and a fine game, too."
> "One o' the best days aht I ever 'ad in me life. **Wish it was then and not nah—straight, I do**. I'm off to Frawnce to-morrer.

It's the text from Goodbye Mr. Chips. What the actor wants to suggest saying  **Wish it was then and not nah—straight, I do**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are remembering a happy day in the past. The speaker wishes that they could go back to that time instead of the present; **nah** is his pronunciation of **now**  - **straight** means **honestly.** I'm guessing that he is about to go to France to serve in the First World War.